# Use of moved value

Tags: rust

I have a simple function in Rust that iterates through numbers and adds them to a vector if they fulfill a condition. This condition is a function that uses a previously defined variable, `prime_factors`.
The `is_multiperfect` function only needs to look things up in the `prime_factors` variable.

```
fn get_all_mpn_below(integer: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let prime_factors = get_prime_factors_below(integer);
    let mut mpn = vec![1];

    for n in (2..integer).step_by(2) {
        if is_multiperfect(n, prime_factors) {
            mpn.push(n);
        }
    }

    return mpn;
}
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
use of moved value: `prime_factors`

      let prime_factors = get_prime_factors_below(integer);
          ------------- move occurs because `prime_factors` has type `HashMap<usize, Vec<usize>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

          if is_multiperfect(n, prime_factors) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I've looked up the error and found it was about ownership, however I fail to understand how ownership applies here.
How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as I don't declare another variable.

Why would you think that's relevant?

*Moving* is simply the default behaviour of Rust when transferring values (whether setting them, or passing them to function, or returning them from functions). This occurs for all types which are not [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

> How can I fix this error?

Hard to say since the problem is `is_multiperfect` and you don't provide that code, so the reader, not being psychic, has no way to know what `is_multiperfect` wants out of `prime_factors`.

Possible solutions are:

- `clone()` the map, this creates a complete copy which the callee can use however it wants, leaving the original available, this gives the callee complete freedom but incurs a large cost for the caller
- pass the map as an `&mut` (unique / mutable reference), if the callee needs to update it
- pass the map as an `&` (shared reference), if the callee just needs to look things up in the map